# How can I compile memcached-1.4.7's source code if I made some change?

Tags: compilation, makefile, memcached, configure, libmemcache

I modified the source code of memcached-1.4.7, but I got stuck when I tried to compile the new code.

I add two files (test.c and test.h) to the source. I modified items.c to call some function provided by test.c. Now I would like to compile the new code. What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: @Dustin Thanks for your reply. There's no specific reason for using this release. 1.4.10 is also fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you try to modify any open-source package, you should *always* try to build a "pritisine" copy first. Usually that's achieved by

```
./configure && make
```

So make another copy of the original source, and build that. *Then* you can try your modifications.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have build the original memcached-1.4.7 and it works well.